# Docker RUN persist environment variables?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

```
FROM bitnami/minideb:latest

RUN . /etc/os-release
RUN echo "code1=${VERSION_CODENAME}"
RUN . /etc/os-release && echo "code2=${VERSION_CODENAME}"
```

When I run this, it prints:

```
code1=
code2=buster
```

Is there some way to persist the environment variables between RUN commands and/or a separate command to load environment variables from a file *inside* the container?

Comment: I don't think you can: https://vsupalov.com/set-dynamic-environment-variable-during-docker-image-build/

Comment: What about ```ENV TESTDATE=`date` ```

Answer (score 4):

In short,

- use `ENV` to set the environment variables into image.
- or `source` your env file at `docker run`

Here is your Dockerfile:

```
FROM bitnami/minideb:latest

RUN . /etc/os-release
RUN echo "code1=${VERSION_CODENAME}"
RUN . /etc/os-release && echo "code2=${VERSION_CODENAME}"
```

According to your Dockerfile, the docker engine will interprete the instructions like this:

1. `RUN . /etc/os-release`: starts an intermediate container from image `bitnami/minideb:latest`, and `source` the file `/etc/os-release`, then commit this container to an image with id (let's say `ab12`)
2. `RUN echo "code1=${VERSION_CODENAME}"`: starts **another** intermediate container from the image `ab12`, which was commited in the previous step. docker engine runs `echo "code1=${VERSION_CODENAME}"` in this container, then commit it to another image `cd34`
3. same as 2. but `source` and `echo` is executed in the same intermediate container.

Apparently, in step 1 and 2, the `source` and `echo` commands are run in different containers, this is why you failed to get the variables you want.

So, the `ENV` instruction is a recommanded way to address your problem. But if you really need to read envs from a file, here is a work-around.

1. prepare a file named `my-env.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
export ENV1=XXX
export ENV2=XXX
# ...
```

2. prepare a file named `entrypoint.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
. /my-env.sh

# rest of the things you wanna do when start this image into a container
```

3. prepare the Dockerfile:

```
FROM bitnami/minideb:latest

# copy files from local to image
COPY my-env.sh /my-env.sh
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

# when start this image into a container, execute the following command
ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "/entrypoint.sh"]
```

4. build image by `docker build -t <repo:tag> .`. Before building the image, your current working directory should contain:

   - my-env.sh
   - entrypoint.sh
   - Dockerfile

Good luck!

Comment: The problem is that the environment variables come from the *inside* the image I'm using. I'm running against `:latest` so the OS codename might change over time. That's why I don't want to hardcode it. I'd just use `ENV` otherwise. Does `ENTRYPOINT` run before the other `RUN` commands..? If it does then that could work.

Comment: No, `ENTRYPOINT` will not be executed before any instructions in the Dockerfile. It will be executed **ONLY** when the image being started into a container.